# Is it better to create a query to return certain results on the backend or frontend? Node vs Redux

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redux

I have a collection that has a number field.  I need to always sum that field to display the result in the UI.

I was wondering if it would be better to sum it on the backend (currently I'm using, Node, Mongo, Express, and Mongoose) and return that through the get response JSON, or create a selector in Redux to calculate the sum and return it?

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what this Number field is and the query requirements of your app, however, some factors that can influence where to do the sum operation would be: 1. How expensive it is? If it’s considerably expensing, it makes sense to push the work to the client 2. Would the initial number value be needed elsewhere in the app? If yes, it makes sense to send the initial value to the client and do the summation there

Comment: Also, not very related but I know there are lot of old tutorials promoting the use of a MongoDB db for web apps but if your project grows, you'll probably be safer using a standard relational database (like PostgreSQL).